# mui-datatables fixedHeader option is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

My requirement is to generate tables using material design in reactjs environment. I want sorting, column hide/show, csv download, fixing of the header while vertical scrolling  and filtering of data of a specific column over the entire table.

I found the below design components:

1. https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/
2. https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables
3. https://github.com/mbrn/material-table
4. https://github.com/techniq/mui-virtualized-table

from the above 4 options, the most suitable package for implementing my table seemed to be **mui-datatables (the 2nd option)** with all the implementations built in for the table component. However, when I am trying to fix the header using fixHeader in options property of the table the header is not fixed for vertical scrolling. To fix the header, I changed the fixedHeader props of the table component in the mui-datable to true. The code for the testing the implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/mmqyr28q6p

Comment: My guess is that the fixed header only works of the table itself is scrollable, which is not the case in your example.

Comment: @darksmurf  if table is made scrollable as for responsive option I have added scroll, still the header is not fixed. btw if you know any table component which has been implemented using material principles in react which can fulfill the above conditions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your table a height then only fixedHeader will work. Put       tableBodyHeight: '400px' in your MUiDatatable options